# Create a PostMan GET Request with JWT

Tags: rest, spring-boot, jwt, postman, restful-authentication

I am new using PostMan; normally I use curl:

this one to get the JTW

```
curl -X POST -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -d '{ "username": "peris","password": "3nRam0nD3L3s0l1v3s" }' "http://139.152.231.107:1133/canPeris/auth"
```

and this other one using the JTW obtained before

```
curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJsb3Blei5hbnRvbmlvODVAZ21haWwuY29tIiwiZXhwIjoxNTkwMDQ3NTg4LCJpYXQiOjE1Mh9.3vlQBgfA22ffJZqNic2lVSHiMR6YudlCFoldfwzdk-clz6_XyOvCVTrMihXtYBaJuPI515zTwAnaQBV_h4yquA"  "http://139.152.231.107:1133/canPeris/api/v1/users/3/menus/vegans"
```

I am using this to generate the token

```
return io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts.builder()
            .setClaims(claims)
            .setSubject(subject)
            .setIssuedAt(createdDate)
            .setExpiration(expirationDate)
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, secret)
            .compact();
```

but in the postMan Signature method I haven't found the HS512

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this can solve your problem.

Goto to **Auth** tab and select **Bearer Token**:

[image]

Add your **Token**:

[image]

Add the header **Content-Type: Application/json**, if necessary:

[image]

**Send your request.**

If you planing automate the access token acquisition and use in another request, I recommend read about postman tests and variables: https://medium.com/@codebyjeff/using-postman-environment-variables-auth-tokens-ea9c4fe9d3d7